# If statement with 9 else conditions in R

Tags: r

I have a function which looks at 9 different possibilities and chooses an action accordingly having the following form:

What I'm doing is looking up a vector and for each entry in the vector deciding

```
IF the value in the vector is 1 THEN start function B
IF the value in the vector is 2 THEN start function C
IF the value in the vector is 3 THEN start function D
IF the value in the vector is 4 THEN start function E
```

etc.

I would like to write this in R. Do I just put "else" for every single case?

I have tried `switch` in the following way:

```
condition<-6
FUN<-function(condition){
    switch(condition,
    1 = random1(net)
    2 = random2(net)
    3 = random3(net)
    4 = random4(net)
    5 = random5(net)
    6 = random6(net)
    7 = random7(net)
    8 = random8(net)
    9 = random9(net)
    10= random10(net))
}
```

Where random 1 to 10 are functions using the variable 'net'

and what the `switch` command is trying to do is checking the value of 'condition' and if its 6 as in the above example then it runs the function: `random6(net)`

Comment: `if/if` and `if/else if` are completely different. Decide which one you need first.

Comment: Also look at `?switch`

Comment: i've edited the question maybe its more clear now

Comment: What's the function to be applied if values in vector are both 1 and 2, or 1 and 3 and so on??

Comment: @RomainFrancois has the answer.  Perhaps the OP could try out `switch` and post his solution as the answer?

Comment: for each separate value there is a separate function but none of them occur together

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `switch` function as in:

```
foo <- function(condition){
  switch(condition,
         '1' = print('B'),
         '2' = print('C'),
         '3' = print('D'),
         '4' = print('E'))
}

> foo(1)
[1] "B"
> foo(2)
[1] "C"
> foo(3)
[1] "D"
> foo(4)
[1] "E"
```

further details are in `?switch`

based on your example:

```
condition<-6
FUN<-function(condition){
    switch(condition,
    '1' = random1(net), # Maybe you're missing some commas here
    '2' = random2(net), # and here
    '3' = random3(net), # and here
    '4' = random4(net)
    ....) # all the way to '10' = random10(net)
}
```

this will do the trick

This works well for me:

```
Foo <- function(condition){
  x <- 1:20
  switch(condition,
         '1' = mean(x),
         '2' = var(x),
         '3' = sd(x))
}

> Foo(1)
[1] 10.5
> Foo(2)
[1] 35
> Foo(3)
[1] 5.91608
```

Comment: this is perfectly fine and thanks for your help, but please see my edit above, what should I put instead of '1' to make it applicable in the above case?

Comment: I get an error message saying :  invalid (do_set) left-hand side to assignment

Comment: this is exactly what I did but I get the error message mentioned in my previous comment

Comment: also: Error: unexpected '=' in:
"                switch(condition,
                1 ="

Comment: @user1723765, maybe you're missing the commas after each condition inside `switch`call

Comment: no, I have the commas and I have no idea what is going wrong then.. The errors refer to the = sign

Comment: If you want `FUN` to be a function, then the `switch` should return `random1` and not `random1(net)`. Then you can evaluate `FUN` by doing `FUN(net)`.

Answer (score 6):

Both answers pointed you to the right tools, but this is IMHO how things ought to be written. The OP and both solutions so far are creating functions that use a global variable (`net`) which is not best practice.

Assuming `randomX` are functions of one argument `net`, i.e.:

```
random1 <- function(net){ [...] }
random2 <- function(net){ [...] }
[etc.]
```

Then you need to do:

```
FUN <- switch(condition,
              '1' = random1,
              '2' = random2,
              [etc.])
```

or better:

```
FUN.list <- list(random1, random2, [etc.])
FUN <- FUN.list[[condition]]
```

In both cases, the output is a function that takes `net` as an input (just like `randomX`) so you can evaluate it by doing:

`FUN(net)`

Also note that you can do everything in one short scoop using the second approach:

```
FUN.list[[condition]](net)
```

Answer (score 5):

Another solution is to pack all the functions you want to call into a list `randoms` and then select a list item based on `condition`:

```
randoms <- list(random1, random2, random3, random4, random5, random6, random7, random8, random9, random10)
FUN <- function(condition) {
  randoms[[condition]](net)
}
```

Comment: +1 - That's the idea, but I think it should just be `FUN <- randoms[[condition]]` to get the right function, then `FUN(net)` to evaluate it. (The OP's code is also messed up with that regards.)